# Spotbugs exclude SEC_SIDE_EFFECT_CONSTRUCTOR for a specific constructor

Tags: java, spotbugs

In my code I often have to call a specific constructor like:

```
Label myLabel = new Label("Hello world");
new QuickTip(myLabel);
```

I know that this is a side-effect constructor and I don't need to assign the created `QuickTip` object. However, as this class comes from a framework, I cannot change that.

Spotbugs correctly reports that as a `SEC_SIDE_EFFECT_CONSTRUCTOR` warning. How can I exclude that without excluding the whole warning type. Also, I don't want to add every method where I use this constructor the my exclude file. Any ideas?

*fyi: It's https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/javadoc/gxt-3.1.4/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/tips/QuickTip.html*

Answer (score 0):

One idea is `-excludeBugs path/to/baseline.xml` option, which ignores bug listed in the baseline XML file.

- https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running.html#output-filtering-options

Or you can annotate methods with [`@SuppressFBWarnings`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.spotbugs/spotbugs-annotations/4.4.2/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/SuppressFBWarnings.html), but it excludes the whole warning type in annotated methods.